# Spark batch delete records on hbase

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I find a lot of examples about loading data in spark from hbase, the one working for me is

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, props.getProperty(ConfigConstants.HBASE_SRC_TABLE_NAME));
    config.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_MAXVERSIONS, props.getProperty(ConfigConstants.HBASE_SRC_TABLE_VERSIONS));
    config.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_COLUMN_FAMILY, HbaseConstants.MAPPING_FAMILY);
    config.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_TIMERANGE_START, "0");
    config.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_TIMERANGE_END, startTimestamp + "000");

    RDD<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>> tupleRDD = context.newAPIHadoopRDD(config, TableInputFormat.class,
            ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class);
```

However I really need a way to delete the records been loaded into spark once they are processed.

Tried to map the tupleRDD into `JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Delete>` and then with

```
JobConf jobConf = new JobConf(config);
    jobConf.setOutputFormat(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat.class);
    jobConf.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, props.getProperty(ConfigConstants.HBASE_TARGET_TABLE_NAME));
    outputPairsRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConf);
```

But this gives me an exception like below

```
"main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set.
```

Is there a way to do the delete from spark?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turn out that there's no simple way to do this, my final solution is to grab the data and delete them through hbase delete function instead of the spark-version delete for hbase.

Comment: there is no solution provided